# recursive formula for pi stumbled upon

Tags: approximation, pi, recursive-algorithms

Looking for a function that would take a long time to test some multiprocess stuff, I calculated x'=sin(x)+x .  To my surprise the values tend towards pi after only a few iterations, for all starting x I've tried less than 4. Why?

Comment: Well, the fixed points are $n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ so it's not all that surprising.  For $0<x<\pi$ we see that $\sin(x)+x >x$ so it can't go to $0$ in that range.  Taking derivatives we see that $f(x)=\sin(x)+x<\pi$ in that range as well...so $\pi$ is the only possible limit point.

Comment: Why would the fixed points be multiples of pi ?

Comment: Because $\sin(n\pi)=0$

Comment: @lulu But the question is also why the convergence is so fast (cubic)